# Install gcc in 32 bit ARM architecture

Tags: c, gcc, arm, buildroot

I've installed BuildRoot, to set a SoftetherVPN. 
Well, my problem is that I necessary need to install GCC, in a 32-bit ARM Architecture, (obviously I've downloaded the 32 bit version).
I looked all over the internet, because of many problems:

My first idea was to install GCC using command `sudo apt-get` or `sudo yum`, but I can only find it in Debian Linux (Buildroot kernel, and its toolchain are very reduced).

At this point I tried to cross-compiling GCC but with no results, because it produced in shell output Library errors. And I also tried to paste those missing libraries yet achieve very little.

Comment: What version of Linux are you using that doesn't have GCC in its repositories?

Comment: @Mr Lister I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in my PC, but I have to install GCC in an circuit board, with Buildroot installed in it

Comment: @LukeTheWolf: are you sure you need a native compiler on the target? In many cases it is not needed. To understand if you really need it, and how you can achieve it, see the Buildroot manual: https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#faq-no-compiler-on-target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could download some GCC [cross-compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-compiler). For example, if your PC is running some Debian-like Linux distribution -perhaps Ubuntu- you might install some `gcc-7-arm-linux-gnueabi` or similar (`gcc-7-arm-linux-gnueabihf` ...) package.

The SDK for your board is likely to provide some cross-GCC & cross-binutils.

You could build some cross [binutils](https://sourceware.org/binutils/) then some [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) cross-compiler from their source code (this is a bit more tricky).

Your cross-compiler would compile (for ARM)  on your Linux-running PC, not on your ARM circuit board.